What is the "shorthand" (or colloquialism) to say "anything in order not to do something/this or that"?
Can't remember for the life of me rn and googling was of no help, can someone help me out?

A closely related saying is

do anything for a quiet life
Strongly prefer and/or try very hard to avoid problems or conflict.
[Farlex Dictionary of Idioms]



rather die than ((not) do something)


(He Fell in Love with His Wife - Edward Payson Roe · 1886) ... he'd rather die than have me do it.
(The Cosmopolitan - Volume 63 - 1917) ... he'd rather die than not to have me love him.
(Can't Let Go: A Bad Boy Romance Gena Showalter · 2017) .. He'd rather die than create a bond with Ryanne.

wow, I had procrastinating in mind, not that dramatic :D
